# Historical aerial imagery GoogleEarth (2014) use in ArcGIS for Central Europe?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, google-earth, historical-imagery

I run the supervised classification of Landsat scene from 2014 to identify forest disturbances.

I would like to assess the **accuracy of my classification** through visual identification of stratified random samplings: however, I do not have aerial photography from this year. **I wanted to use historical GoogleEarth (GE) imagery (from 2014) to assess my accuracy.**

Is there a way to open the Historical GE imagery in ArcGIS 10.1? I have found that no, but maybe there are some updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When asked:

> if Arc2Earth would allow me to bring historical Google imagery (such
>   as 2007) into ArcMap?

its developer, [Brian Flood, replied on 7 Oct 2015](http://help.arc2earth.com/help/discussions/questions/1017-historical-imagery):

> unfortunately no. if Google ever adds historical imagery to the Google
>   Maps API, we will definitely add it to Arc2Earth